# Explain the comments in leetcode for the definition of a binary tree

Tags: python

Im trying to solve questions on leetcode but the first 6 commented lines always confuse me, can someone explain what it actually means.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def lowestCommonAncestor(self, root: 'TreeNode', p: 'TreeNode', q: 'TreeNode') -> 'TreeNode':
```

Answer (score 0):

The commented lines tell you the class definition for `TreeNode` which is the class type of the parameter `root`, `p`, and `q`.

They give this information to you because `TreeNode` is not a built-in type in Python, but they want you to be able to know how to use the parameters `root`, `p`, and `q` (and also how to build the return type)

For example, you can see that in the comments `TreeNode` has properties `self.val`, `self.left` and `self.right`. This means that to get the value of the `root` node given to you, you can do `root.val`. Likewise to get the left and right subtree you can do `root.left` and `root.right`

Lastly, it also shows you the constructor definition (`def __init__()`) for `TreeNode` which tells you how to construct one:

```py
myNewTreeNode = TreeNode(1)  # TreeNode with one node that has value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the class `TreeNode` will be provided to you and that will be the definition of the class. The parameters of the function `lowestCommonAncestor` are of type `TreeNode`